# Efficiently sending values to GLSL shader

Tags: opengl-es, glsl

I am trying to write my particle system for OpenGL ES 2.0. Each particle is made up of 4 vertexes, forming the little square where a transparent texture is drawn.

The problem is: each particle has its own properties (color, position, size), that are constant across the 4 vertexes of that particle. The only variation for each vertex is what corner of the square it is.

If I am to send the properties of the particle via uniform variables, I must do:

```
for(each particle) { // do maaaany times
  glUniform*(...);
  glDrawArray(...); // only draw 4 vertexes
};
```

this is clearly inefficient, since I will only draw 4 vertexes per glDrawArray call.

If I send this properties via attribute variables, I must fill the same information 4 times for each fragment in the attribute buffer:

```
struct particle buf[n];

for(each particle) {
  struct particle p;
  p = ...; // Update particle
  buf[i+0] = buf[i+1] = buf[i+2] = buf[i+3] = p;
};

glBufferData(..., buf, ...);
// then draw everithing once afterwards...
```

what is memory inefficient and seems very ugly to me. So what is the solution to this problem? What is the right way to pass parameters that change for each few vertexes to the shader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [point sprites](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_point_sprite.txt). The introduction is very explicit about how to solve your problem.

You can also combine the use of point sprites with another extension, [point_size_array](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_point_size_array.txt).

...

As Christian Rau has commented, the point_size_array is no more usefull using programmable pipeline: set the maximum point size as usual, then discard fragments basing on their distance from the point center, derived from texture coordinates generated by OpenGL. The particle size shall be sent via additional attribute.

Comment: Since he uses ES 2.0 he can just use a custom float attribute and delegate this to `gl_PointSize`, no need for `OES_point_size_array`. But +1 for point sprites in general, whose standard application are indeed particle system. Though they have some problems (center-based clipping), these might be negligable with small particles.

Comment: Looking more closely to the spec, I could not figure out how to get the texture coordinate from inside the fragment shader. The spec seems to assume fixed function pipeline (that does not exists in OpenGL ES 2.0).

Comment: After some search, I found this: http://klazuka.tumblr.com/post/249698151/point-sprites-and-opengl-es-2-0
Apparently none of these extension apply anymore, but as @ChristianRau said, +1 for point sprites.

Comment: @Ivella From your link it rather seems point sprites are always supported in ES 2.0. And like said in the link, just get the in-sprite texture coordinate from the builtin `gl_PointCoord` variable. So where's the problem?

Comment: Note that point sprites have limitations. A point sprite can only be so large. Also, points are clipped at the *center* of the point, so if the center of a particle moves off-screen, the entire thing disappears.

Answer (score 2):

GL ES doesn't really have a good solution to this. Desktop OpenGL allows for instancing and various other tricks, but ES just doesn't have those.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Uniform Buffer Object](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object). Note that this feature is only available on D3D10+ hardware.

Comment: I guess this is not likely to be supported in ES.

Answer (score 0):

Send the information via a texture. I'm not sure that texture sampling is supported in opengl-es 2.0 vertex shaders, but if it is, then that would be optimal.

Comment: Regarding that texture access is everything else than free or even fast, I'm not sure this would really be optimal, but it has to be evaluated. Together with render-to-texture this might enable particle update directly on the GPU.

Comment: Well compared with sending massive amounts of data via uniforms (especially if this is a particle system with a decent amount of particles), I would think that this is a faster solution.